# Python and appending items to text and excel file

Tags: python

I am wondering how I can append items in a list all into specifics rows because for some reason my python code does some whacked stuff.

```
Yvalues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
open("file.csv", "w")
file_out = open('file.csv','wb')
mywriter=csv.writer(file_out)
for item in Yvalues:
            mywriter.writerow(Yvalues)
file_out.close()
```

When I open my csv file I get this:

```
1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5
```

I don't want that layout, how can I make it so that it goes to a specific row all going down like this:

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is as follows:

```
Yvalues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
file_out = open('file.csv','wb')
mywriter=csv.writer(file_out, delimiter = '\n')
mywriter.writerow(Yvalues)
file_out.close()
```

This will give you:

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

Comment: hi sorry, i made typoin question i just reworded it.

Comment: @user152573, Yes. I assumed you made a mistake. Still my answer works for your case

Comment: how would i go about designating specific rows for the appending. Lets say I wanted to put the values in row 3 in the csv file

Comment: @user152573, Easiest would be to write two empty lines

Comment: I tried your method, but I got this error "Error: sequence expected" when i use (item)

Comment: @user152573, Answer updated to be more clear. Please note __ALL__ the changes i made to your code. including the delimiter

Comment: Thank you so much, and to go back to what u said earlier, what did you mean by writing empty lines if i wanted to designate specific rows?

Comment: @user152573, So if you want to write in line 3, you can write an empty string to line 1 and line 2 and then write whatever you want to line 3.

Comment: @user152573, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks

Comment: Darn, everytime i try to write to the same file new values, it always goes to the first row. What should I do so that it won't keep writing to same row?

Comment: @user152573, You probably want to open your file in the append or `a` mode. Try looking at some examples online.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your values correctly mapped. Try this version:

```
y_values = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
with open("file.csv", "w") as file_out:
    mywriter=csv.writer(file_out)
    mywriter.writerows(y_values)
```

You were using *writerow* which will take the given value is the contents for a row.  Since you are passing it the same list every time, its assuming you want five columns.

In my version, I am using *writerows*, and my list contains a list representing each row. Since there is only one item in each inner list, that's what will be written.